# truncate-string-to-width doesn't pad/print the string, as documented

Tags: string, table

I am referring the documentation for `truncate-string-to-width` from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-of-Displayed-Text.html).

It says,

```
(truncate-string-to-width "\tab\t" 12 4)
```

will output,

```
ab
```

But what i get in my machine (emacs versioned 25.1.50.1) is one tab character with no alphabets printed. And similarly, when i do

```
(message "%s"
                 (truncate-string-to-width "\tab\t" 12 4 ?\s))
```

my mac shows, one tab character plus six space chars. But the documentation quotes,

`⇒ "    ab  "`

Why does `truncate-string-to-width` truncate the alphabets in my machine?

Comment: What Emacs version is it?

Comment: (emacs versioned 25.1.50.1)

Comment: Same on `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1671) of 2018-10-01`